# What is "main" parameter for nginx access_log?

Tags: nginx

In many nginx config tutorials I see this:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main
```

What is `main`? It is not found in [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second parameter of the `access_log` directive is an optional `format` name, which determines the content of a log file entry.

The default format is `combined`, which is predefined as:

```
log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

See [this document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) for details.

The format named `main` should be defined by a `log_format` directive elsewhere in your Nginx configuration. Use the command `nginx -T` (with an uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files.